# How can I set a window as ActiveWindow programatically in a unit test?

Tags: ocean

I'm writing a test for a plugin that needs an active Window3D.

I add it and try to set it active with

```
var window = PetrelProject.ToggleWindows.Add(WellKnownWindows.Window3D);
PetrelProject.ToggleWindows.Active = window;
```

but `PetrelProject.ToggleWindows.Active` is still null. Is there some background processing that needs to be done before the new window is actually active? How can I test code that needs an active window?

I'm using Petrel 2012.1.

Comment: Are you using the Test framework?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the framework that was shipped with the Ocean SDK where NUnit is starting a background Petrel session.

Comment: Please see @MBen's answer below

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the `PetrelEngine` you will not get the Window systems, thus the `ActiveWindow` will be always `null`.

Your test will work only if you start the real Petrel.

If this is an important use case, please write an email to your portfolio contact.